# Let $B$ be simetric and positive definite. Show that $x^T\left(B - \frac{Bss^TB}{s^TBs}\right)x $ is also positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, positive-definite

Let $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ simetric and positive definite and $s\in\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$

Let $$M := B - \frac{Bss^TB}{s^TBs}$$

Show that $$x^TMx > 0$$

My try:

$$x^TMx$$

This is $$x^T\left(B - \frac{Bss^TB}{s^TBs}\right)x $$

$$=x^TBx - \frac{x^TBss^TBx}{s^TBs} $$

We know that for any nonzero  $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$  $$x^TBx > 0$$

I'm not sure on what to do with the numerator  $x^TBss^TBx$ in order to obtain that

$$x^TBx > \frac{x^TBss^TBx}{s^TBs}$$

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: You mean $s\in  \Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are really close!

Recall that any positive definite matrix defines an inner product $\langle u,v\rangle=u^TAv$ Here your matrix $B$ also defines an inner product, thus the required inequality could be rewritten as
$$
\langle x,x\rangle \langle s,s\rangle\geq (\langle s,x\rangle)^2
$$
which is proven by [Cauchy Schwartz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). QED.

However I feel the form $x^T\left(B - \frac{Bss^TB}{s^TBs}\right)x
$ is **positive semi definite, not positive definite**, since when $x=s\neq 0$ this form is $0$.